# How to share audio file from raw folder into social apps?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to add sharing option to my soundboard app and now I have a problem with taking audio files from raw folder.

I was trying make sharing function using that code:

```
 public void onClick(View v){
                String sharePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                        + "/res/raw/sound1.mp3";
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("audio/*");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
            }
```

But Messenger and other apps have problem with take audio file from my app. Should I make script first to save audio on phone storage and then use that file to share in other apps?

Answer (score 1):

Resources are files on your development machine. They are not files on the filesystem of the device.

> Should I make script first to save audio on phone storage and then use that file to share in other apps?

Copy the resource to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) somewhere (e.g., `getCacheDir()`) and set up `FileProvider` to allow you to share the content.